# BigQuery error in load operation: Cannot determine table described by UTF-8

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to load data to already created table in big query. But I have facing the above issue. How could I resolve this issue?

```
bq '--project_id' <proj-id> --nosync load --source_format CSV --field_delimiter '\t' --skip_leading_rows '0' --quote '' --encoding UTF-8 <proj:dataset.table_name> '/mnt/disks/data.tsv'
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried executing your command and it succeeded. Most probably your shell is not properly handling empty `--quote` parameter, and so it looks like: `--quote --encoding` when executed. Try invoking this instead (`--quote ''` is replaced with `--quote=''`):

```
bq '--project_id' <proj-id> --nosync load --source_format CSV --field_delimiter '\t' --skip_leading_rows '0' --quote='' --encoding UTF-8 <proj:dataset.table_name> '/mnt/disks/data.tsv'
```

If it does not work, please share OS and shell names (bash / zsh / cmd?) for the further investigation.